# DataTables Editor FreeTDS connection on GNU/Linux

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, datatable, freetds

I'm starting to use Editor DataTables (http://editor.datatables.net/).

I made a Web Projecto on Ubuntu Linux, PHP, Apache And Mysql.
And all works fine, but now, I need to connect to SQL Server on Windows Server but I can't connect because I don't have the sqldrv installed because it is only available for Windows.

Actually I've installed FreeTDS and y made many test:

freetds.conf:

## A typical Microsoft server

```
 [mssql]
   host = IP_SERVER
   port = 1433
   tds version = 4.2
```

odbc.ini:

```
 Description = FreeTDS
 Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
 Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
 Database = plan_vuelo
 ServerName = mssql
 TDS_Version = 4.2
```

odbcinst.ini:

[FreTDS]

```
 Description = FreeTDS
  Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
  Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
  client charset = utf-8
```

Command output = tsql -C:

```
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v0.91
             freetds.conf directory: /etc/freetds
     MS db-lib source compatibility: no
        Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 4.2
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: yes
```

When I run a tsql the connection is succesfull:

```
$ tsql -S mssql -U sa -P Radec866
locale is "es_MX.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
1> select top 1 * from [plan_vuelo].[dbo].pv1_roles;
2> go
idRoles nombre  email   vendedor    responsable torre_control   admin   idUsuario   idSucursal
1   Vendedor Matriz micke_hp_2.0@hotmail.com    1   0   0   0   1   1
(1 row affected)
1>
```

When I run a isql:

```
$ isql -v mssql sa Radec866
SQL> select TOP 1 nombre, email from [plan_vuelo].[dbo].pv1_roles;
+-------------------------+--------------------+
| nombre                  | email                                                     
| Vendedor Matriz         | micke_hp_2.0@hotmail.com 
SQLRowCount returns 1
1 rows fetched
```

All my test connection are succesfull, but I have no idea that how edit the **/php/lib/Database/Driver/Sqlserver/Query.php**

```
try 
  {
    $pdo = new PDO(
    `"sqlsrv:Server={$host}{$port};Database={$db}".self::dsnPostfix( $dsn)`,
    $user,
    $pass,
    array(
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ));
  } 
catch (\PDOException $e) 
  {
    // If we can't establish a DB connection then we return a DataTables
    // error.
    echo json_encode( array( 
      "sError" => "An error occurred while connecting to the database ".
      "'{$db}'. The error reported by the server was: ".$e->getMessage()
    ));
    exit(0);
   }
```

This is my **Config.php** file:

```
$sql_details = array(
    "type" => "Sqlserver",
    "user" => "sa",
    "pass" => "Radec866",
    "host" => "IP_SERVER",
    "port" => "",
    "db"   => "plan_vuelo",
    "dsn"  => "mmsql"
);
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance!